# vload4 vs 4 individual memory accesses : bank conflicts

Tags: opencl

What is the advantage of vload4 over 4 single memory accesses?

Suppose I am loading memory from local memory. Below are two kernels. 
The second kernel should exhibit no bank conflict. Does the first have bank conflicts?
Because, if one vload is executed per clock, then there should be conflicts.

```
void kernel1(__local int* localBuffer) {

    int start = get_local_id(0)*4;
    int4 test = vload4(start,localBuffer);

 }


 void kernel2(__local int* localBuffer) {

   int4 test;
   int start = get_local_id(0)*4;
   test.x = localBuffer[start];
   test.y = localBuffer[start+1];
   test.z = localBuffer[start+2];
   test.w = localBuffer[start+3];

 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two kernels you show are equally bad on GPUs.  vload4 does not get executed in a single clock cycle on either Nvidia or AMD GPUs when accessing local memory.  It gets executed as a sequence of 4 loads.  To avoid bank conflicts on GPUs you should rather be stepping a multiple of `get_local_size(0)`, i.e. using `test.w = localBuffer[start+3*get_local_size(0)];`.  If you are using 2 or 3 dimensions then the step should be `get_local_size(0) * get_local_size(1) * get_local_size(2)`.

The situation changes a bit for CPUs.  On CPUs the local memory is actually just part of global memory and CPUs have assembler code instructions to load an int4 vector in a single operation.  A good compiler should use this native vector load for vload4 and will hopefully be smart enough to see that kernel2 can also use the vector load operation (assuming you don't disable optimizations).  Of course, this also depends on whether the compiler tries to use vector operations within a single work item or to group multiple work items together.  If it does the latter then kernel2 might not get optimized to use a single vector load, resulting in reduced memory throughput.

Comment: Thanks, Chippies. May I ask where this is documented about vload4 on GPU? I couldn't find it anywhere.  Really appreciated your answer and advice.

Answer (score 0):

The advantage is that adjacent work items reads could be coalesced. The individual reads have no chance to do that.

Comment: Thanks, Dithermaste. But, I thought only reads from global memory are coalesced. From what I have read, local memory accesses are all of the same latency as long as there are no bank conflicts.

Comment: Indeed. I missed that is was a local buffer. In that case, probably no different.